# Auto resize carousel image with fix height of 500px and full width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty satisfied with my carousel which is working fine execp two things which i would like to change and counting your help.

Question:
How to make images to be fitted to carusel? Right now they are cutted from bottom - see on image (blue line) - but note that the height has to be kept to 500px always and carusel image has to be fully width from left to right as it is now. So the only one thing is to centralize image. How its cutted marked on blue.

Additionaly i would like to remove navbar which i can see appearing on top of carusel every image (navigation arrows has to stay). - marked on red

This is how it looks like currently:

[image]

Carousel code:

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="new/3.jpg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img alt="" src="new/1.jpg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img alt="" src="new/2.jpg">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
              <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
              <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Css code:

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: -90px;             /* odstep miedzy carusel slider a nastepnym containerem tzn O mnie */
    }

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 550px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 500px; 
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: static;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }


    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .featurette {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .featurette-image.pull-left,
      .featurette-image.pull-right {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .featurette .lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

    }
```

**LATER TRIES...**

I was trying to play with that but unfortunety what i did was the image was centralized - but image was not aligned fully from left to right, and from bottom to next contener element ("Kilka slow..") has diffrent distance. That was the code below and output:

carusel:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/1.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/2.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div style="background:url(/images/3.jpg) center center;
          background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
  </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.END CAROUSEL DIV -->
    </div><!-- /.END MYCAROUSEL DIV -->
</div><!-- /.END BSEXAMPLE -->
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
      margin-bottom: -90px;             /* odstep miedzy carusel slider a nastepnym containerem tzn O mnie */
    }

.slider-size {
    height: 500px;
}

    .carousel .container {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 9;
    }

    .carousel-control {
      height: 80px;
      margin-top: 0;
      font-size: 120px;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }

    .carousel .item {
      height: 550px;
    }
    .carousel img {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      height: 500px; 
    }

    .carousel-caption {
      background-color: transparent;
      position: static;
      max-width: 550px;
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin-top: 200px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1,
    .carousel-caption .lead {
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1.25;
      color: #fff;
      text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
    .carousel-caption .btn {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }


    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
    -------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (max-width: 979px) {

      .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .featurette {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .featurette-image.pull-left,
      .featurette-image.pull-right {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto 20px;
      }
    }


    @media (max-width: 767px) {

      .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
      }
      .carousel .container {

      }
      .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
      }
      .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
      }
      .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .carousel-caption .lead,
      .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
      }

      .marketing .span4 + .span4 {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .featurette .lead {
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 1.5;
      }

    }
```

preview:

[image]

[image]

Sorry for such long post but hope theres anyone who can solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would go with the background image technique. something like...

```
<div class="item active" style="background-image: url('images/1.jpg')">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.item{
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

EDIT ********

I would appreciate if you didn't just vote down when I wrote "something like this to be used". Here is a fiddle using slick slider which i would advise you use https://jsfiddle.net/tonytansley/c4n547at/. Im not 100% sure what you are after.

Comment: Please let me know if you are unable to work this, as it is something I regularly do in my own websites.